# AngularJs, how to pass a value from one page to another page?

Tags: angularjs

Basically, I just need to pass one id value from one page to another page when clicking the link. Is there any example I can follow?

Comment: What do you mean pass value from one page to another page? Do you mean from one route to another route within the same single page app? Take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just from one .html to another .html file.

Comment: There are many ways to pass values from one page to another, you can try URL parameters, cookies, local storage. Do some research, try it and if you still can't accomplish it but have some code to work from there, StackOverflow might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service or a factory.  Below, I've created `myfactory` which exposes a `setSomething` and a `getSomething` method.  Since factories and services are singletons, these values will remain over the lifetime of the app (unless you manually change them).  So, when `controller1` does `myfactory.setSomething('hi')`, anything which calls `myfactory.getSomething()` will get *hi* until something else does `myfactory.setSomething('something else');`

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('controller1', controller1)
  .controller('controller2', controller2)
  .factory('myfactory', myfactory);

function controller1(myfactory) {
  myfactory.setSomething('hi');
}

function controller2(myfactory) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.something = myfactory.getSomething(); // hi
}

function myfactory() {
  var something;
  var setSomething = function(something) {
    this.something = something;
  }

  var getSomething = function() {
    return something;
  }

  return {
    setSomething: setSomething,
    getSomething: getSomething
  }
}
```

Comment: I can only save the value on that page. When I link to another html, the value stored in factory is empty, and I can get nothing.

Comment: @YunfengZhao, I see.  I thought you were implying this was an Angular Single Page App.  With that, as mentioned in the comments, there are many ways to do that, one would be `localStorage`.  You can use that like `localStorage.setItem('myKey', myValue);` and then on any page that wants the value can do something like: `var something = localStorage.getItem('myKey');`